# OLS estimator in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I am new to liner algebra and currently looking at the matrix expression for calculating the ordinary least squares estimator:

[image]

Can anyone provide a little intuition on the right hand side expression? I have worked through this with matlab and it feels a little like magic that his clever bit of math results in the OLS. I can't see how squaring and summing each Xi, taking the inverse and then multiplying each Xi with the result gets you anywhere near the OLS. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here is a good set of notes that derives this equation and should build some intuition: https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/13/lecture-13.pdf

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: As an update to this question in case anyone was interested; since asking, for me there was no real intuition to be gained from the matrix form. The intuition comes from looking at the expanded equations. The matrix form is just a convenient way to express these caluclations compactly - working through a full example will make this clear.